# Force the generation of HTTP links in HTTPS mode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, https, security

I'm using SSL in my ASP.NET MVC 3 application. Once that the user enters in HTTPS mode, all the links in the page are generated with the HTTPS preface, but I'd like to "let the user leave" the HTTPS mode, and get back to HTTP when critical information exchange has been already done.

Is there anyway in the Routes configuration or something to say something like:

```
/Home/Index will be always HTTP
```

I've tried with:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home",null,"http")">Normal</a>
```

But it fails when I'm using a custom port. I mean, at the beginning it is: `http://127.0.0.1:5104/Home/Index` but when the link is generated from HTTPS it looks: `http://127.0.0.1/Home/Index` and of course it doesn't work

Regards.

Comment: how do you expect the web page to know which port the http is running on?

Comment: Because 'Request.Url.Port' ?? The page is generating the links with the correct port when it's in HTTP mode, as I said.

Comment: but the port on the request is different if the request was done through HTTPS, so you would need to know which port is in use on the http side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the user is browsing an HTTPS page, the request itself doesn't contain any information with respect to what port the HTTP binding is running on. which means that you would need to supply it yourself (it might be possible to get this value out from the IIS config file somehow).

Below is a sample helper function that allows you to specify which http port the request should be routed to.

```
public static string HttpAction(this UrlHelper helper, string action, 
    string controller, object routeValues, int port)
{
    var url = helper.Action(action, controller, routeValues, "http");
    var uri = new Uri(url);

    var builder = new UriBuilder(uri.Scheme, uri.Host, port, uri.AbsolutePath, uri.Query);
    return builder.ToString();            
}
```

Usage:

```
@Url.HttpAction("index", "account", new { val = 5 }, 5055);
```

Comment: You're totally right and your method works great! I've added an optional parameter to specify the protocol, so I can use it with the https links as well. Thanks a lot! I'm so focus on Azure that as the endpoint configuration is there, i forgot that it has nothing to do with the MVC routing configuration. Cheers.